# Pay with BTC in online stores accepting only CCs

Tags: bitcoin-credit-card

I'm looking for a way to spend BTC to buy products / services in stores that accept only credit cards. I know it's possible with virtual credit cards. Any examples of such services? Or something like all4btc -- it was a company where one could send btc and an URL of the product to buy and they took care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

so depends on what you are looking to buy. I know someone that used XCH4NGE lifestyle to buy a car recently. you can find them on twitter. @xch4ngelifestyle.